# Detecting unhandled mouse events

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

The question is probably a bit more complex than the title might make you believe, but in the end it nails down to that question. But first let me show you the bigger picture:

I am using chromiums rendering/content/javascript engine for user interfaces in my application. Below the user interface though is a real 3d world that also needs to be informed about interaction. So you can imagine my user interface like a regular html page where the body is transparent. So whenever i get a message for the user interface (like mouse move, mouse down and so on) i need to be able to detect if that message was handled by the user interface or if it should be propagated to the world "below". All this only has to work in chrome, other browsers are unimportant.

So far i had the following ideas (i keep using mouse move as an example):

- Attach a mouse move handler to window (or html or body) and when its hit -> deliver to the application. Problem here is that events get propagated up the chain no matter if handled or not
- Attach a mouse move handler to window and check if the event target is html or body. Problem here is if i have like a tansparent container div thats only used for positioning or arranging child nodes i will get this element if its hovered even tho it should go to the world there
- Attach a mouse move handler to window, mark elements that should not capture the mouse (like transparent divs) with an attribute and in the mouse move handler check if the target has such an attribute. If yes, then fire the event, else its handled. Problem here is if one of these nomouse-elements is over an element that wants to capture the mouse i miss it
- Attach a mouse move handler to window, mark elements that should not capture the mouse with an attribute. Add a mouse move handler to all elements that do not have the no-mouse attribute and set a property to true. in the window mouse handler check if that property in the event object is set. This could work i think.

Is my last idea feasible? Do you know of a better way to achieve this? Greetings and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a transparent div over the whole screen and attach the mouse handler to it. Use the z-index for placing the clickable elements in front of it.

**The whole screen div CSS:**

```
html, body {
    weight: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#whole-screen {
    min-height: 100%; 
}
```